# Ethernet LAN Dongle is constantly disconnecting (USB3)

Tags: ethernet, lan

Edit: Must be a driver problem. The UGREEN ASIX AX88179 is constantly disconnecting on one of my ports (see below). I ordered an ANKER dongle wich works stable on both ports.

It's using:

```
Realtek RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter type: USB driver: r8152
```

My HW:

```
Kernel: 5.4.0-62-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: MSI model: H81M-E34 (MS-7817) v: 3.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           BIOS: American Megatrends v: 17.5 date: 03/30/2015 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-4460 bits: 64 type: MCP L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           Speed: 3361 MHz min/max: 800/3400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3345 2: 3385 3: 3335 4: 3316 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.2.6 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: BEHRINGER UMC204HD 192k type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio 
           Device-3: AKAI Professional M.I. type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-62-lowlatency 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
           IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: d8:cb:8a:e8:e9:99 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter type: USB driver: r8152 
           IF: enx00e04c000176 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 00:e0:4c:00:01:76 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 537.79 GiB used: 95.49 GiB (17.8%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 850 EVO 250GB size: 232.89 GiB 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: Samsung model: Portable SSD T5 size: 232.89 GiB 
           ID-3: /dev/sdc type: USB vendor: Transcend model: JetFlash Transcend 16GB size: 14.71 GiB 
           ID-4: /dev/sdd type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Ultra size: 57.30 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 36.41 GiB used: 12.20 GiB (33.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
           ID-2: /home size: 184.23 GiB used: 83.29 GiB (45.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 7.45 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 32.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 216 Uptime: 25m Memory: 7.23 GiB used: 1.81 GiB (25.0%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

I ordered a UGREEN ASIX AX88179 USB 3 ethernet dongle and I'm having some issues with it: I tested it on an USB 2 port and there the dongle seems to work fine. On the back I tested it on two USB 3 ports. On one of the ports the network is constantly diconnecting and reconnecting. The journal entry looks like this:

```
    Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: unregister 'ax88179_178a' usb-0000:03:00.0-3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: usb 6-3: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:03:00.0-3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 00:0e:c6:74:5d:eb
Jan 13 23:07:21 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: unregister 'ax88179_178a' usb-0000:03:00.0-3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet
Jan 13 23:07:21 marco-MS-7817 kernel: usb 6-3: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
Jan 13 23:07:21 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:03:00.0-3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 00:0e:c6:74:5d:eb
Jan 13 23:07:24 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: unregister 'ax88179_178a' usb-0000:03:00.0-3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet
Jan 13 23:07:24 marco-MS-7817 kernel: usb 6-3: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
Jan 13 23:07:24 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:03:00.0-3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 00:0e:c6:74:5d:eb
Jan 13 23:07:30 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: unregister 'ax88179_178a' usb-0000:03:00.0-3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet
Jan 13 23:07:31 marco-MS-7817 kernel: usb 6-3: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
Jan 13 23:07:31 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:03:00.0-3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 00:0e:c6:74:5d:eb
Jan 13 23:07:41 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: unregister 'ax88179_178a' usb-0000:03:00.0-3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet
```

and the complete version:

```
Jan 13 23:07:06 marco-MS-7817 named[800]: managed-keys-zone: Key 20326 for zone . is now trusted (acceptance timer complete)
Jan 13 23:07:15 marco-MS-7817 systemd-resolved[617]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.178.1.
Jan 13 23:07:16 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 avahi-daemon[653]: Interface enx000ec6745deb.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: usb 6-3: USB disconnect, device number 27
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: unregister 'ax88179_178a' usb-0000:03:00.0-3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: Failed to read reg index 0x0002: -19
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 avahi-daemon[653]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enx000ec6745deb.IPv4 with address 192.168.178.33.
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 NetworkManager[662]: <info>  [1610575638.2244] device (enx000ec6745deb): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 avahi-daemon[653]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.178.33 on enx000ec6745deb.
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 whoopsie[2095]: [23:07:18] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 whoopsie[2095]: [23:07:18] offline
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 named[800]: no longer listening on 192.168.178.33#53
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 NetworkManager[662]: <info>  [1610575638.2287] dhcp4 (enx000ec6745deb): canceled DHCP transaction
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 NetworkManager[662]: <info>  [1610575638.2287] dhcp4 (enx000ec6745deb): state changed bound -> done
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0001: -19
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 NetworkManager[662]: <info>  [1610575638.2296] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 dbus-daemon[661]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=662 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconf>
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 dbus-daemon[661]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 nm-dispatcher[18403]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: usb 6-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: usb 6-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0b95, idProduct=1790, bcdDevice= 1.00
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: usb 6-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: usb 6-3: Product: AX88179
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: usb 6-3: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: usb 6-3: SerialNumber: 00000000000179
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 NetworkManager[662]: <info>  [1610575638.8005] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/143)
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:03:00.0-3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 00:0e:c6:74:5d:eb
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 mtp-probe[18413]: checking bus 6, device 28: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/usb6/6-3"
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 mtp-probe[18413]: bus: 6, device: 28 was not an MTP device
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 systemd-udevd[18384]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 systemd-udevd[18384]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: renamed from eth0
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 NetworkManager[662]: <info>  [1610575638.8301] device (eth0): interface index 143 renamed iface from 'eth0' to 'enx000ec6745deb'
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 NetworkManager[662]: <info>  [1610575638.8368] device (enx000ec6745deb): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 mtp-probe[18418]: checking bus 6, device 28: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/usb6/6-3"
Jan 13 23:07:18 marco-MS-7817 mtp-probe[18418]: bus: 6, device: 28 was not an MTP device
Jan 13 23:07:19 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: ax88179 - Link status is: 1
Jan 13 23:07:21 marco-MS-7817 ModemManager[802]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/usb6/6-3': not supported by any plugin
Jan 13 23:07:21 marco-MS-7817 kernel: usb 6-3: USB disconnect, device number 28
Jan 13 23:07:21 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: unregister 'ax88179_178a' usb-0000:03:00.0-3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet
Jan 13 23:07:21 marco-MS-7817 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
Jan 13 23:07:21 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: Failed to read reg index 0x0002: -19
Jan 13 23:07:21 marco-MS-7817 kernel: ax88179_178a 6-3:1.0 enx000ec6745deb: Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
```

On the USB 3 port next to the one from above the connection is much more stable and it lost connection only once (which of course is also not acceptable).

The driver is part of the kernel and the device should work without any issues. However when searching the web there are more people having similar issues with USB3 (also on Windows or Mac). I can exchnage the dongle and just get another one which works. Can you recommend something? Is realtek for example "the better" firmware?

I also don't understand why there's such a big difference between the two USB3 ports. I copied a 3GB several times to a USB Stick connected to the "bad" USB port and checked the sha sum. It's working fine, so I guess the port is not the problem.

My system conf:

```
Kernel: 5.4.0-60-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: MSI model: H81M-E34 (MS-7817) v: 3.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           BIOS: American Megatrends v: 17.5 date: 03/30/2015 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-4460 bits: 64 type: MCP L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           Speed: 3309 MHz min/max: 800/3400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3277 2: 3386 3: 3334 4: 3336 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.2.6 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: BEHRINGER UMC204HD 192k type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio 
           Device-3: AKAI Professional M.I. type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-60-lowlatency 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: d8:cb:8a:e8:e9:99 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 635.72 GiB used: 204.64 GiB (32.2%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 850 EVO 250GB size: 232.89 GiB 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: Samsung model: Portable SSD T5 size: 232.89 GiB 
           ID-3: /dev/sdc type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Ultra size: 57.30 GiB 
           ID-4: /dev/sdd type: USB vendor: Transcend model: JetFlash Transcend 128GB size: 112.64 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 36.41 GiB used: 11.53 GiB (31.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
           ID-2: /home size: 184.23 GiB used: 79.05 GiB (42.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 7.45 GiB used: 47.2 MiB (0.6%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 30.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 221 Uptime: 1h 20m Memory: 7.23 GiB used: 2.11 GiB (29.2%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38 


lsusb -v -s 006:009

Bus 006 Device 009: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x0b95 ASIX Electronics Corp.
  idProduct          0x1790 AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0039
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              496mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              4 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              11
        bMaxBurst               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the USB ports more than anything else. If the connection is "loose", then there's a good probability that the network connection will disappear and reappear often as contacts make and break connections. I see this all the time at work where students are plugging and unplugging USB memory sticks of all shapes and sizes. If the USB connector is not snug on the lead, then it's going to have issues.

Comment: I checked the USB port with an USB 3.0 stick and and an USB 3.0 card reader and it's working fine with those. I also measured the voltage which is between 4.99 ad 5.00 V. I ordered another hub and see if this behaves different (Realtek driver this time).

Comment: The Anker USB Ethernet Adapter is working on both ports. I'll added the info in the question.

Comment: Recently I ordered three AX88179-based adapters and all of them are strangely disconnecting under specific heavy load. I even filed a bug report to Mainline: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212731

Comment: I'm having this issue in Windows 10 too, must be driver/hardware issue.